# deleting Broken Source from arcgis toc with python addin

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-addin

i have created one python addin tool. which create some layers in Memory. at the end of the script it deletes the In memory layer. but such layer still remains in TOC with a broken link

[image: layer with broken link]

how can i remove such layer in python ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is property isBroken - Returns True if a layer's data source is broken.

```
   for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*", df):  
        if layer.isBroken:  
            arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, layer)
```

[Link to Esri help](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm)

Comment: isBroken Property is not working

Comment: is there any error or something?

Comment: apologies, i did something wrong in script, its working fine, thanks a lot.